# ASP treeview not rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have a asp.net bootstrap website. When I drag a treeview onto my aspx page and use autoformat on any of the options the expand buttons are extremely large and I cannot resize. Is there a css trick or something im doing wrong to fix this?

[image: asp.net treeview]

```
   <div style="text-align: left">
            <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" CssClass="accordion-toggle collapsed" ShowCheckBoxes="All" ImageSet="Arrows">
                <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" />
                <NodeStyle Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="5px" NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
                <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
                <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
            </asp:TreeView>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer, you will need to add the main.css or native asp.net css file to your solution that is not present when you create a bootstrap themed asp.net web application.